# Getting NullPointerException from Play framework

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have been using play framework 2.2.4 version. While executing particular action getting `NullPointerException`, If its from my code I can fix it but it has come from play library.

could someone help on this??

```
# action #
public static Result getOverViewPage(final String errorMsg){   

    String autoBillStatusMsg = "";
    //business logic is here
    Logger.info("Final Auto-pay status message : "+autoBillStatusMsg);
    return ok(rave_customer_index.render());
}
```

We are able to see the above logger statement. But after that we are getting NullPointerException

## Exception StackTrace

> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/18 15:15:24 | [info] application - Final
>   Auto-pay status message :
>
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/18 15:15:24 | [error] play - Cannot invoke
>   the action, eventually got an error: java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/18 15:15:24 | [error] application - INFO
>   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/18 15:15:24 | INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/18
>   15:15:24 | ! @6nfm0a093 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->
>
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/18 15:15:24 |
>
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/18 15:15:24 |
>   play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution
>   exception[[NullPointerException: null]]
>
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/18 15:15:24 |       at
>   play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:296)
>   ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
>
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/18 15:15:24 |       at
>   play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:402)
>   [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
>
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/18 15:15:24 |       at
>   play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320)
>   [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
>
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/18 15:15:24 |       at
>   play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320)
>   [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
>
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/18 15:15:24 |       at
>   scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
>   [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na] INFO   | jvm 1    |
>   2015/09/18 15:15:24 |
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/18 15:15:24 |       at
>   java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:205) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
>
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/18 15:15:24 |       at
>   play.api.mvc.CookieBaker$$anonfun$3.apply(Http.scala:427)
>   ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
>
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/18 15:15:24 |       at
>   play.api.mvc.CookieBaker$$anonfun$3.apply(Http.scala:426)
>   ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
>
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/18 15:15:24 |       at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
>   ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
>
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/18 15:15:24 |       at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
>   ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
>
> DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2015/09/18 15:15:25 | send a packet PING : ping
>
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/18 15:15:26 | WrapperManager Debug:
>   Received a packet PING : ping
>
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/18 15:15:26 | WrapperManager Debug: Send a
>   packet PING : ping

Comment: Can you please paste some code where are you getting this Exception?

Comment: @curious I have updated code in the description